# Secure home network configuration?

Tags: home-networking, wireless-router

Now My home network configuration is as follow:

**SPEEDTOUCH ST536 (use as a modem)** ---> (...wired via ethernet line...) ---> **BELKIN MODEM/ROUTER F5D7632-4 (use as a wireless access point)**

Now, there is an internet connection and it works fine but I don't know how to setup WEP for security purpose. Now, my neighbor can use my wireless signal and it is bad.

After searching for a solution, some said that i need to set WEP key on router by browsing to my router's ip address: 192.168.1.1 but this lead me to THOMSON SPEEDTOUCH page (a modem) which there is no option for setting up WEP KEY at all. (I have tried some variation: 192.168.0.1, 192.168.2.1. The browser say it cannot connect to those addresses.)

Can somebody just help me out? I want to set WEP to allow only authorized person who know the key to use my network.

Sorry for poor english. But I need an urgent help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use WPA2.  WEP is what came first, and then it was replaced with WPA because it wasn't secure enough, and now there's WAP2 which provides even better security.

If your router doesn't support WPA2 then check with the manufacturer for a firmware update (this is software that is normally available for free).  If your router can't support WPA2, then buy a new one that does (I've had really good success with the LinkSys/Cisco brand, and all modern brands and models should support WPA2).

With free/open-source tools like AirSnort (and a variety of others) one can observe a small number of packets on a WEP network to find out what the password is (browsing a typical web site with graphics on it will usually generate plenty of packets for this purpose).  Low security is one of the reasons people don't use WEP anymore.

Also, if someone tells you that you can secure your network by limiting by MAC/node address (a.k.a., the physical hardware address of the network cards in your computers), they are wrong because most network card drivers make it a trivial matter to specify a custom MAC/node address.  With packet sniffing, they can easily determine what your node address is, and then configure this in their computer and your router won't know the difference.

P.S.:  Give your wireless network a creative name that won't provide your neighbours with any hints that it might be you.  Although this isn't really a security technique, it does keep the nosy neighbours from bothering you with "oh, I see you have a wireless network, can I borrow access to it?"

Answer (score 0):

I think that model is 192.168.2.1

See this guide if that does not work

http://portforward.com/networking/routers_ip_address.htm

.

Belkin user guide

http://www.belkin.com/uk/support/article/?lid=enu&pid=f5d7632uk4a&aid=5591&scid=0

If all else fails just connect the router to the PC without the modem, reboot, then try ip config to find the ip of the router, enter that and configure encryption, I would not use wep, use WPA2.

.